# scikit-learn: One hot encoding of column with list values

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scipy, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to encode a dataframe like below:

A       B             C
2      'Hello'      ['we', are', 'good']
1      'All'        ['hello', 'world']

Now as you can see I can labelencod string values of second column, but I am not able to figure out how to go about encode the third column which is having list of string values and length of the lists are different. Even if i onehotencode this i will get an array which i dont know how to merge with array elements of other columns after encoding. Please suggest some good technique

Comment: Use [Multilabelbinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) to one hot encode that feature. See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42392689/3374996)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we have the following DF:

```
In [31]: df
Out[31]:
   A      B                C
0  2  Hello  [we, are, good]
1  1    All   [hello, world]
```

Let's use [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

```
In [32]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [33]: vect = CountVectorizer()

In [34]: X = vect.fit_transform(df.C.str.join(' '))

In [35]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vect.get_feature_names()))

In [36]: df
Out[36]:
   A      B                C  are  good  hello  we  world
0  2  Hello  [we, are, good]    1     1      0   1      0
1  1    All   [hello, world]    0     0      1   0      1
```

---

alternatively you can use [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) as [@VivekKumar suggested in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711861/scikit-learn-one-hot-encoding-of-column-with-list-values/42713749#comment72545486_42711861)

```
In [56]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

In [57]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

In [58]: X = mlb.fit_transform(df.C)

In [59]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(X, columns=mlb.classes_))

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
   A      B                C  are  good  hello  we  world
0  2  Hello  [we, are, good]    1     1      0   1      0
1  1    All   [hello, world]    0     0      1   0      1
```