# Scikit-learn f1_score for list of strings

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter

Is there any way to compute f1_score for a list of labels as strings regardless their order?

```
f1_score(['a','b','c'],['a','c','b'],average='macro')
```

I wish this to return 1 instead of 0.33333333333

I know I could vectorize labels but this syntax would be far easier, in my case, since I am dealing with many labels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is the f1_score for a multilabel classification task and for that you need a 2-d matrix for `y_true` and `y_pred` of shape `[n_samples, n_labels]`.

You are currently supplying a 1-d array only. Hence it will be considered as a multi-class problem, not multilabel.

The [official documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#multiclass-and-multilabel-classification) provides the necessary details.

And for that to be scored correctly you **need** to convert the `y_true`, `y_pred` to  label-indicator matrix as [documented here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html):

> **y_true** : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix
>
> **y_pred** : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

So you need to change the code like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

y_true = [['a','b','c']]
y_pred = [['a','c','b']]

binarizer = MultiLabelBinarizer()

# This should be your original approach
#binarizer.fit(your actual true output consisting of all labels)

# In this case, I am considering only the given labels.
binarizer.fit(y_true)

f1_score(binarizer.transform(y_true), 
         binarizer.transform(y_pred), 
         average='macro')

Output:  1.0
```

You can have a look at examples of MultilabelBinarizer here:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392689/3374996