# one hot encode a binary value in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a numpy array that looks like the following:

```
array([[0],[1],[1]])
```

And I want it to be represented as the one hot encoded equivalent:

```
array([[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]])
```

Any body have any ideas? I tried using [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer) but this just re-produces the input.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

As requested, here is the code using LabelBinarizer

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer

train_y = np.array([[0],[1],[1]])
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(train_y)
label_vecs = lb.transform(train_y)
```

Output:

```
array([[0],[1],[1]])
```

Note that it does state in the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.LabelBinarizer) 'Binary targets transform to a column vector'

Comment: How are you using the LabelBinarizer. It is supposed to get it right. Post your code and current output (you said it just re-produces the input)

Comment: updated as requested

Comment: Ok. For your specified output (`array([[1,0],[0,1],[0,1]])`), you can use MultiLabelBinarizer. Look its usage in my other answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42392689/3374996. But

Comment: But this is very confusing. Why do you want to one-hot encode your target (`train_y`). Is this a multi-label classification problem. If not then you should stick to LabelBinarizer and the output is correct

Comment: I'm trying to build a neural net using tensorflow where I am predicting 1 or 0.  As such, the labels used for the network must be representative of this. There is a method in tflearn I have just found which will do what I want, [http://tflearn.org/data_utils/#to_categorical](tflearn.data_utils.to_categorical)

Comment: Is OHE necessary? we can't just leave it 0,1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use `sklearn`, it seems we could use [`OneHotEncoder`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), like so -

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

train_y = np.array([[0],[1],[1]]) # Input

enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(train_y)
out = enc.transform(train_y).toarray()
```

Sample inputs, outputs -

```
In [314]: train_y
Out[314]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [1]])

In [315]: out
Out[315]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.]])

In [320]: train_y
Out[320]: 
array([[9],
       [4],
       [1],
       [6],
       [2]])

In [321]: out
Out[321]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

---

Another approach with `initialization` -

```
def initialization_based(A): # A is Input array
    a = np.unique(A, return_inverse=1)[1]
    out = np.zeros((a.shape[0],a.max()+1),dtype=int)
    out[np.arange(out.shape[0]), a.ravel()] = 1
    return out
```

Another with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
def broadcasting_based(A):  # A is Input array
    a = np.unique(A, return_inverse=1)[1]
    return (a.ravel()[:,None] == np.arange(a.max()+1)).astype(int)
```