# Vectorizing terms inside a column of strings in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, text-mining

I have a table-like dataset with the following structure: each line has, as columns:

```
RecipeName: "Guacamole"
Ingredients: "Avocado, vinegar, tomato"
PreparationTime: 10
```

I want to convert this to a bag-of-words-type representation in a pandas DataFrame, so that this line becomes

```
(column names) RecipeName Avocado Broccoli Chocolate Tomato Vinegar Zucchini
               Guacamole      1       0        0        1      0        0
               WeirdCacao     0       0        1        1      0        0
```

(I'm obviously able to take a DataFrame with a single Ingredients column and convert it into a dict of lists:

```
 recipe_dict = {recipes.ix[m]['RecipeName']:recipes.ix[m]['Ingredients'].split(',') for m in recipes.index}
```

But I'm not able to use CountVectorizer on that. Maybe that's not even the best way to handle it. )

Comment: You can use [Multilabelbinarizer here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html). Check my [other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42392689/3374996)

Answer (score 0):

I brute-forced an answer to this specific problem; but I'd still like to know how to do this with scikit-learn, as I might want to switch to tf-idf later, for example.

Given the dict obtained by

```
recipe_dict = {recipes.ix[m]['RecipeName']:recipes.ix[m]['Ingredients'].split(',') for m in recipes.index}
```

We do the following:

```
from functools import reduce
ingredients = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, recipe_dict.values())
```

to obtain a list of all ingredients and then loop

```
for j in ingredients:
    recipes[j] = recipes['RecipeName'].apply(lambda i: 1 if j in recipe_dict[i] else 0)
```