# Hot encode variable length list of vectors

Tags: python, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I am new to python and needed help with this. So I have list of tensors like -

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'punk'], dtype=object)>

,
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'hiphop'], dtype=object)>,


 <tf.Tensor: shape=(33,), dtype=string, numpy=
 array([b'pop', b'beautiful', b'female vocalist', b'90s', b'80s',
        b'heard on Pandora', b'favorites', b'soft rock', b'female vocals',
        b'melancholic', b'1990s', b'covers', b'sing along', b'nostalgic',
        b'my favorite', b'great song', b'favs', b'1990', b'wooees',
        b'Girl Groups', b'celeste nostalgia', b'Foxy Lady', b'trios',
        b'The 80s', b'elementary school', b'lentos', b'wings of love',
        b'on a rainy day', b'female vocal groups', b'Greatest Cover Songs',
        b'glen ballard', b'wilson phillips',
        b'wilson philips-a reason to believe'], dtype=object)>,
```

etc.

I want to hot encode these tags based on particular tags - say I want to hot encode based on soft rock, punk, hiphop for each and every tensor in the list. Any recommendations?

Comment: This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391165/how-to-one-hot-encode-variant-length-features